# How to traverse a binary tree and count the occurrence of a value without passing in a value

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, tree-traversal

I am currently working on a program to implement a binary search tree. The struct for the tree is as follows:

```
struct treeNode {
    Type value;
    int count;
    treeNode* left;
    treeNode* right;
};
treeNode* root;
```

I am trying to implement the following function:

```
template <class Type>
int bstree<Type>::count(){

return count(root);
}

template <class Type>
int bstree<Type>::count(treeNode* sroot){


}
```

I am trying to figure out how I would visit every node and add up all the count values for each node.

Comment: Ok so whats the question?

Comment: @Borgleader, I don't understand how exactly to visit every node.

Comment: What is it counting? Or is it adding up all the `count` fields?

Comment: @ZackHerbert We do understand what you want - but not where your problem is. You should show what you have tried and where you failed.

Comment: @Galik it would simply sum up all the count fields

Answer (score 2):

```
template <class Type>
int bstree<Type>::count(treeNode* sroot){
   int ret = 0;
   if ( sroot )
   {
      ret = sroot->count;
      ret += count(sroot->left);
      ret += count(sroot->right);
   }

   return ret;
}
```

Comment: okay, I will try this. I am still struggling with recursion, so that I my biggest issue with figuring these methods out

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you're passing an argument... wouldn't this do it?

```
template <class Type>
int treeNode<Type>::get_count()
{
    int result = count;
    if (left) result += left->get_count();
    if (right) result += right->get_count();
    return result;
}
```

and then you call `root->get_count();`

Comment: The method headers were given to my by my professor. They may not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Some crazy C++ there

The only way I can see you could do it is to have a global variable which is updated by two callback functions, one goes left and the other right. You start at the first node. Each node you reach needs to result in a launch of another instance/thread of these functions. Recursion may be unsuitable because it could lead to a stack overflow. You need to create two new threads at each node to walk from the current tree node left and right. I had thought at first there was a chance of walking into a node more than once but now I realise that should never happen because a left right move will always take place at another level of the tree. I am assuming you have implemented the tree correctly because if you accidentally create a circular queue/list with pointers, welcome to infinity, unless you flag each value off that has been counted as suggested earlier.

I have not used C++ for years but you must be able to cast a pointer to list then you could cheat and not need any of the above just move through it sequentially.